# Raise event from control in library

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I see there's some similar questions to what I have to ask, but I have been reading through them and still not sure how to solve my issue. I've only been using WPF for a couple months, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

I am including an open source control in an application I am working on, it is an auto complete text box found here: https://wpfautocomplete.codeplex.com/
This control is in vba, I work in C# - I can follow what's going on in it, but its not a language I am strong in.

Within this control there is an event when the selected item in the AutoCompleteTextBox is changed:

```
Shared Sub OnSelectedItemChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim act As AutoCompleteTextBox
    act = TryCast(d, AutoCompleteTextBox)
    If act IsNot Nothing Then
        If act.Editor IsNot Nothing And Not act._isUpdatingText Then
            act._isUpdatingText = True
            act.Editor.Text = act.BindingEvaluator.Evaluate(e.NewValue)
            act._isUpdatingText = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

When this happens I would like to call an event within my application that passes on the object `e` to allow processing on it. I am currently looking into the [UIElement.RaiseEvent method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1). Am I on the right track?

If so, then how to I 'catch' the raised event in the xaml/codebehind of my c# wpf application that's using this control?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking at is used internally by the user control to perform some action when the value of the `SelectedItem` property changes, and won't be much use (unless you modify the source - you could add an `event` and raise it from within that method). The "WPF way" is to use data binding, but this assumes you are using MVVM. Just bind the control's SelectedItem property to a property on the view-model, like this:-

```
<wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ...
```

It sounds like you aren't using MVVM though. If not, one solution is to use your code-behind class as the "view model". In the constructor, set itself as the DataContext, e.g.:

```
public YourConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = this;
}
```

This now lets you bind XAML control properties to properties on your code-behind class. Make sure the code-behind class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx)) then add a property that will be bound the control's SelectedItem property:-

```
public object SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedItem != value)
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");

            // Do whatever you need to, when the selected item changes
        }
    }
}
```

Bind this to the control's SelectedItem property (as per my earlier XAML snippet), and you should be good to go. This provides you with a simple way to utilise data binding without going for a full-blown MVVM application.

Comment: Ah okay, I was thinking about the problem in the wrong way. Thanks for the pointers, that makes more sense now. I have been able to get this working now using MVVM, the drop down contains my Model classes and I'm able to bind other controls to the attributes of the selected model via the DependencyProperty. Good stuff!